What is the meaning of " ribbon-infested hellscape "?
From Dickinson S01E03: Timestamp 17:45

Sue Gilbert : Why are you in Lavinia's room?
Emily Dickinson : I got lost. And now I'm in this ribbon-infested hellscape. Ow!
Sue Gilbert : Are you dying?
Emily Dickinson : I hope so.
Sue Gilbert : Emily, what is wrong?
Emily Dickinson : I got my period.

What does this phrase mean? What is "ribbon-infested hellscape"? Meaning behind relating the situation of getting periods to ribbon-infested hellscape. Is there any poetic meaning ?

I think you're overthinking this one. Lavinia's room has lots of ribbons and bows. Emily isn't a very 'girly' girl and she's not enjoying the classical femininity of the room, describing it as a hellscape.
